# Why my question on Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange getting downvotes without explanation?

Tags: discussion

Why my question on Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange getting downvotes without explanation (comments)? Is this usual in Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange community?

I wonder if I got the downvotes because I don't want to open a Google account. Did I criticise surveillance capitalism too much? How to improve the question?

question: [Watch Youtube videos without “personal API key”, because I don't have a Google account](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/108663/watch-youtube-videos-without-personal-api-key-because-i-dont-have-a-google-a/108691#108691)

EDIT:

**Offtopic:**

- most users use RPI for Kodi based media center. It's not intended main use case from the vendor, but the most popular for users. Lots of kodi questions (even tag) on this Stack Exchange.

**copyright protection**

- It has nothing to do with copyright protection. It's just a privacy issue. Copyright very different in American countries comparing to for example China or Russia.

Comment: "most users use RPI for Kodi based media center. " - Are you sure about this?

Comment: I know about 15 Raspberry Pi users, and not one of them, including me, uses them for Kodi.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is impossible to say for sure, since there is nothing overtly wrong with the question *except* that it is somewhat off-topic here (there are already 3/5 votes needed to close it without a moderator).

"Off-topic" is a grey area here and it is up to the community to decide; the only things that categorically aren't eligible are questions where you cannot take "Raspberry Pi" out (or substitute it with "computer" or "linux OS") without rendering the question meaningless.

The other thing may be that someone at a glance thinks you are trying to circumvent copyright protection of some sort -- perhaps you are, I know nothing about the topic, but I don't think so (without having searched for info at all, I'm happy with my guess that the API key is for google tracking).  But some people may just see "Kodi", "youtube", and "without key" and think differently.

Technically we don't have rules against people asking questions which violate some country's laws, but there are regular users here who consider it a duty to represent their country and its laws.

Anyway, -2 isn't exactly bombarded outrage, you could put it down to a few cranks.

Comment: This is a good and reasonable answer +1. I've had no real problems with downvotes here, but some sites are brutal (or maybe it's me?... nah, couldn't be :)  While discussing this same point w/ a moderator on SE Brutal, I pointed out that the [**Expected Behavior**](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/behavior) includes a statement to `Add comments indicating what, specifically, is wrong.` Not throwing stones as I live in a house with some glass, but I do feel in **most cases** this is a good thing to do. OTOH, I s'pose it may lead to *discussion* that's unproductive.